# Tmux monitor activity change highlight color

Tags: tmux

I'm setting up my tmux.conf and I want to have the activity monitor with different colors. I would like to change the color of the highlight of the alerted window in the status bar.

The problem come when I try to change the color of the background. I'm using this options shown on the tmux manual page.

```
# activity window
setw -g monitor-activity on
setw -g window-status-activity-bg red
setw -g window-status-activity-fg yellow
```

When I reload the configuration I can see that the color of the letters in the alerted window change to red but I can't find the way to change the highlight of the alerted window.

What I'm missing?

EDIT: I'm using tmux 1.6 maybe updating to 1.9 solve the problem.

Thank you.

Comment: I suppose asking this on http://unix.stackexchange.com/ would give better results.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because belongs on another site, and appears to have been moved there by the OP

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56060443/how-do-i-set-window-title-color-in-tmux-2-9a/56814607#56814607